# tikzpicture[ ] and axis[ ] do not align

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, scaling

I would like to combine figures drawn outside of the scope of axis but inside the scope of \tikzpicture with figures inside the \axis environment. However they seem to leave in a different reference space.  I provide a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,shapes, pgfplots.external}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\R{1}
  \fill[ball color=white!10] (0,0) circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=none,
      samples=50,domain=0:360,y domain=0:90,
      xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2,zmin=0,zmax=1.2]
    \pgfplotsset{
      colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}
    }
    \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.6, shader=interp]
    ({cos(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(y)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The figure is next:
[image: axis do not align]

Since I have not said anything about origin and scale, the two coordinate systems should be on synch but they have different origin and different scale. Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First, the coordinate system in a `pgfplots` axis is completely separate from that of the surrounding `tikzpicture`. Remember that an `axis` has a default width (240pt), and it will have that size regardless of the range. For example, if you have two `axis` environments, one with `xmin=0,xmax=1` and one with `xmin=0,xmax=10`, they will still have the same width. Thus, 1 unit length in the first axis will be 10 times longer than in the second axis, when printed on paper.

Second, I think this may get complicated by the fact that you're mixing 2D and 3D. Consider this image, where the axis box is shown:

[image]

That the height ended being "correct" in the code below was just luck I think. The unit vectors in the axis, in a 2D reference system, will depend on the `view`, `width` and axis limits, so how to get the correct width is not obvious to me.

## Old answer (slightly edited)

An `axis` will always have its own coordinate system, I'm not sure why you expect them to be the same. The `axis` is placed with its `south west` corner (the default anchor) in `(0,0)` by default. If you add `name=theAx` to the `axis` options, and add e.g. `\fill (theAx.south west) circle[radius=3pt];` you will see that this is placed in the center of your shaded circle.

If you want the origin  of the `axis` to be in the center of the circle, add `anchor=origin` to the `axis` options. <s>To get about the same scale, you will need to make sure that 1 unit in the `axis` coordinate system is the same as 1 unit (by default, 1cm) in the `tikzpicture` coordinate system. I guess that with your settings of `xmin` and `xmax`, adding `scale only axis,width=2.4cm` will make it about right.</s> Scaling is more complicated as explained above, and I don't really have a good solution for that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\R{1}
  \fill[ball color=white!10] (0,0) circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=none,name=theAx,anchor=origin,
      samples=10,domain=0:360,y domain=0:90,scale only axis,width=2.4cm,
      xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2,zmin=0,zmax=1.2]
    \pgfplotsset{
      colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}
    }
    \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.6, shader=interp]
    ({cos(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(x)*cos(y)}, {sin(y)});
  \end{axis}
\draw [red] (theAx.south west) rectangle (theAx.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Tobjorn : This is good. I still do not understand the scaling. Do I have to do trial and error to find the right scale? I will also try scope. I expect that if both are under the same \begin{scope}[shift={0,0}, scale=1.0] ... \end{scope} they might be in synchronization. I would expect that.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo What I said above was a bit wrong, will see later if I can figure out a better solution. And no, you shouldn't expect that a `scope` will help.