# How to color a curve with many smooth transitioning colors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to "draw[]" a color line starting in green, ending in blue and a transition between green and blue in a smooth continuous fashion. For example in tikz/pgf plots we can use a command such as:

```
\shade[bottom color=gray, top color=green] (D)--(O)--(B);
```

to color a triangle with gray and green with a smooth (gradient) transition.

A more specific example is shown in this figure generated with gnuplot,
but I do not want to plot a function, and I do not want axes. I just want to draw[] a line or an arc. In other words, I want to "shade[]" a curve in a rainbow coloring.

[image: smooth color on curve]

This is not a repeated question: I have seen these posts with similar questions: [coloring edge segments with different colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270001/tikz-coloring-edge-segments-with-different-colors)

and also: [plotting a curve with different colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98492/plotting-a-curve-with-different-colors)

That is not what I want.

Is there a function in TikZ or PGS (no pstricks or metapost please) that do this?

Thanks.

---

**Update**:

Here is my poor man solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


    \begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
      \foreach \t in {0.,0.01,...,1}
      {
      \coordinate (A) at (\t, \t);
      \def\scl{20}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\s{\scl*\t}
      \draw[color=blue!\s!green]  (A) circle (0.1mm);

      }

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

and here the plot:

[image]

The main problem here is that the curve is
 hard coded. So, for another curve, I would need a new code.

I will work on creating a macro for a general path.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: it is possible with pgfplots. There must be a few duplicates of this

Comment: @percusse : Let us say I define \coordinate (A) at (0,0); \coordinate (B) at (0,1) then draw[ color=gradient between blue and green] (A)--(B) ?

Comment: Look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling.

Comment: Or this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/path-following-color-gradient-in-tikz

Comment: OSjerick : Your pointers are excellent!  I did not want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Section 4.7.6 of the `pgfplots` documentation shows how to define your own colormap, but you need to take slightly different approaches to apply the map to symbols or lines.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap={greenblue}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,255); rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,0)}]
    \addplot+[scatter,scatter src=x,samples=50]{sin(deg(x))};
    \addplot[mesh,ultra thick,point meta=x,samples=50]{cos(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good with pgfplots but I need to draw a segment form (A) to (B). I am uneasy about the \begin{axis} ... \end{axis} environment because I have not been able to align the axis outside of this scope. I believe I can remove the axis, but integrating this "axis" environment with TiKz has been hard for me. Thanks

Comment: Please see this question that I posted in Nov 15:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/tikzpicture-and-axis-do-not-align   Since, at the moment, I have not been able to align tikzpicture[] axis with axis[]   "axis" I prefer to stay away from the "axis[]" environment. Thanks.

Comment: @erik , is there a way to specify parts of the curve to be colored? i.e. from 0 to pi/2 green and so on.

Comment: @riccs_0x I would use separate `\addplot` commands with a defined `domain` for each.